# Can Blender 3.5 render 3D videos in 180 degree or 360 degree formats, for playback on a VR headset like the Quest 2?

Tags: vr

I'm looking for tutorials that will show me how to create 3D videos, for VR. I tried looking on Google and YouTube, but I'm not finding anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'll be sure to post links to the videos that I create.

Also, is it possible to download templates that have all the correct settings in place?

Answer (score 0):

If rendering with Cycles, you can render out videos with an equirectangular projection. First make sure that the active rendering engine is Cycles. With a camera object selected, go to the camera properties objects on the right, and change the Type to Panoramic and the Projection to Equirectangular.

[image: Camera properties panel]

Comment: Will the result be a 3D video file?

Comment: There would be nothing inherently different about the file format itself, now would there have to be. It's just that the projection of the scene's contents onto 2D window that is the video would be changed to make it suitable for an equirectangular sampling. This is usually how 360 degree videos are made/formatted. e.g. such a video would work with something like YouTube's 360 degree video feature.